# What’s the difference between “用” (you) and “使​っ​て” (tsukatte)?

Tags: word-choice

What’s the difference between “[用](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=52745&j=%E7%94%A8)” (you) and “[使​っ​て](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=tsukatte&e=&search=Search%20%3E)” (tsukatte)?
Both mean “to use”, but when would you use one over the other? Are they interchangeable?

*Please explain by making reference to the below examples.*

> **reitou-you Binīru fukuro**
>
> plastic bag used for freezing
>
> **Facebook ya SNS wa tsukatte imasu ka?**
>
> Do you use Facebook or social media?

Please note: I am a beginner, so would appreciate answers that aren't too complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 用 in 冷凍**用**ビニール袋 is a noun suffix which means something like 'used for', 'for the purpose of' etc.

使って in フェイスブックやSNSは**使って**いますか is the te-form of the verb 使う meaning 'to use'.

These are completely different pieces of grammar and are not at all interchangeable. If you don't know about the te-form then I suggest you go and research it. It is an absolutely vital and fundamental thing to learn. There are loads of resources on the internet that will teach you about this.

Comment: Just comparing 使う(root form) and 用: Why does 冷凍用ビニール袋 use a noun suffix instead of a verb? Is it because Freezing is a verb and so you need to use a suffix to link the noun to the verb?

Comment: Not really. Besides which, 冷凍 is a noun. 冷凍する is the verb form. I suppose you could say 冷凍に使うビニール袋 if you really wanted to use 使う. I guess its like the difference between talking about a 'freezer bag' and 'a bag used for the purpose of freezing'. Which one would use choose in English?